# How to backtrace a variable in php template

Tags: theming, debugging

Currently I am in a .tpl.php file, and have the following piece of code:

```
  <?php if ($rows): ?>
  <div class="view-content">
    <?php print $rows; ?>
  </div>
  <?php elseif ($empty): ?>
  <div class="view-empty">
    <?php print $empty; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

It seems extremely difficult to figure where the $rows variable comes from. Any good idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and [ddebug_backtrace()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/ddebug_backtrace/7) api function exposed by devel..

Below is the function call stack for page.tpl.php executed using below command..

```
<?php dpm(ddebug_backtrace());?>
```

[image]

I believe above tpl is related to views module... **$rows are generated dynamically by views module based on your views settings...**

Comment: So I install and enable devel, then I add <?php dpm(ddebug_backtrace());?> to the code I mentioned above, and refresh the page. But nothing shows up. Am I using it in a wrong way?

Comment: Oops, never mind, I forget to login as admin, thanks!

Comment: Are you accessing page as admin ?

Comment: Actually it is not completely done. I did the similar thing in xdebug. The problem is I don't know where the '$rows' variable being created. I try to search keyword 'rows' in every files of the backtrace but still no clue.